# Is there any difference these two pieces of js code?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cross-platform

Can you tell me if the two following codes' meanings are exactly the same (under all OS, including Mac, which I can't test)?

**Code 1**

```
if($('#mail1').val()==$('#mail2').val()){} 
else{
alert("Mail inputs don't match!");return;
}
```

**Code 2**

```
if($('#mail1').val()!=$('#mail2').val()){
alert("Mail inputs don't match!");return;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code is redundant, you don't need the `if-else`, the second one is more correct but this is even more correct:

```
if($('#mail1').val() !== $('#mail2').val()){
  alert("Mail inputs don't match!");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me if the two following codes' meanings are exactly the same

Yes they are.

I see an *empty* `if` block sometimes in code. My guess is some developers find it easier to read or the *empty* `if` block serves as a future placeholder. Either way, I don't use or advocate such coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

It does but you should use === instead of ==   or !== instead of != .
The triple equals avoids the type coercion.

Comment: While I agree that `===` is good practice, in this case there'll be no coercion since it will always be a string to string comparison.

Comment: it's a good coding practice. Clearly the OP is new to JS and should get into the habit of using it.

Comment: Another point to make is that .val() may return an array if field is multivalue field.

Comment: In the case of a multiple select, I'd suggest that the coercion of the `==` would be desired. Imagine if both inputs have `"foo"` as their value, but one of them is a multiple. The `==` will perform a `toString` conversion on the Array, resulting in a comparison of `"foo" == "foo"`, which would provide the desired result, since from the developer's perspective, both inputs were assigned the same value. But the strict `===` will see them as unequal, which would be an odd result for the intended task.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the same.  You have:

```
if (something) then do nothing
else do this-action
```

and

```
if (not something) then do this-action
```

Same, yes?